# After using a storyboard segue the Tab bar is not showing

Tags: ios, swift

There are some similar questions but not exactly the same, and some are quite old.
Basically the tab bar is going missing after I'm doing a performSegue on a button press.

The view controllers are laid out in the storyboard but I'm putting the text and buttons into them programatically.
Segues 1 & 2 are storyboard segues which are the kind "Present Modally". In the top right view controller when one of the buttons are pressed it sets a variable and performs Segue 2. This is where the Tab Bar is not visible.

Segue 3 is a relationship segue and you can see when it's selected (1st image) it shows the Tab Bar on "Second View". But in the 2nd image it shows segue 2 selected and the Tab Bar is missing.

I'm calling segue 2 like this:

`performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChapter", sender: self)`

Based on what I've read I think perhaps I need a Navigation Controller somewhere. Currently I have no navigation controllers so to test my code I have to Stop execution and start again.

If anyone can tell me how to have the Tab bar showing after segue 2 it would be much appreciated.

[image: Tab Bar Showing]

[image: Tab Bar Missing]

Comment: Embed your controllers in Navigation Controller and change the segue kind to Push, not Modal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500866/why-tabbar-hides-after-the-segue/35501541

Comment: may be this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796673/tried-to-pop-to-a-view-controller-that-doesnt-exist-swift-5-1-xcode-ios/59798564#59798564

Comment: Keshu R. I put the Book Menu & Second View view controllers in Navigation controllers. Does the blank view controller at the top right need to go in a navigation controller as well? I also changed the segue to a Push, but the Tab bar is still not showing after the segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobels solution is on the right track, I tried it, but it didn't work.
In the end what did the trick was a button on the top right View Controller which did a self.dismiss and then changed the tabbarcontroller selected index.

Here is the function called by a button. (chapter selection button)

```
@objc func selectChapter(button: UIButton) {
    CurrentChapter = button.tag
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    if let tabBarController = self.presentingViewController as UITabBarController {
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please uncheck Hide Bottom Bar on Push in storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom UITabbarController with an unwind @IBAction

   ```
   class CustomTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

       @IBAction func unwindToVC2(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
           dismiss(animated: true) {
               self.selectedIndex = 1
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. Create manual unwind segue in a modal presented view controller (ctrl-drag from File’s Owner to Exit) and set it's identifier to "segueFromVCXToVC2"
3. In modale presented view controller perform the custom unwind segue

   ```
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueFromVCXToVC2", sender: nil)
   ```

This will dismiss a modal view controller and select the second tab of the tabbar view controller

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Adobels. Your solution makes sense to me, but I don't know where to put the code in step 1. I put it in the BookMenu view controller file in a separate class, but the unwind segue is not going to this unwind function now, like it will if the unwind function is in the view controller class. Where should it go?

Comment: I don't think I have any UITabBarController code in my project.